# How to use MVVM Light DispatcherHelper with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I have a Xamarin Forms application that was created using the standard Xamarin.Forms Shared solution template for Visual Studio.

The Android project uses a `MainActivity` class that derives from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity`.

Within this solution, I am hoping to use the `DispatcherHelper` component from the MVVM Light Toolkit.

However, whenever I attempt to use `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()` to marshall to the UI thread, the app throws an `InvalidOperationException`, as follows:

```
The DispatcherHelper cannot be called.
Make sure that your main Activity derives from ActivityBase.
```

Looking at the inheritance hierarchy of `FormsApplicationActivity`, I can see that it does not derive from `ActivityBase`, so this clearly explains the problem.

However, I wonder if there is an alternative way of using this `DispatcherHelper` that is compatible with Xamarin Forms or, alternatively, an alternative base class from which I can derive my `MainActivity`.

Many thanks for your suggestions,

Tim

Comment: The only thing that `CheckBeginInvokeOnUI` does on Android is to call  `RunOnUiThread`, can you not just use Xamarin.Forms' `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`?

Comment: @SushiHangover: Yes, I guess that's an option, but I was hoping to avoid it because my view models are also shared by a non-Xamarin (UWP) application. But I agree that it's not so difficult to create an interface that exposes this functionality and inject its platform-specific implementations. Thanks.

Comment: Non-Xamarin app? Whats that? ;-) ... You could always patch the mvvm light `ActivityBase.CurrentActivity` code to allow for  `V7.App.AppCompatActivty` and `App.Activity` ;-)